# Angularjs: directive does not update view binding scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive which takes care on requesting data to server and define a scope property to show on the view, the directive also has a function for creating new requests and whether the new requests is responded, the view should be updated with the new data.. but the problem relies on the second step, which is updating the view

so the directive is constructed like this:

```
app.directive("restBatch", ["restFactory", "utilityFactory", function($rest, $util){
    function batch(uri, cb){
        $rest.batch(uri)
            .then(function(data){
                cb(data);
            });
    };

    return {
        restrict: "A",
        controller: ["$scope", function($scope){
            //Create a new request and update the view with the new data
            $scope.$search = function(data){
                var uri = this.$uri + "?q" + $util.querySearch(data);

                batch(uri, function(data){
                    $scope[this.$name] = $scope.$inline ? $util.group(data, $scope.$inline) : data;
                });
            }
        }],
        link: function(scope, element, attr){
            var call = $util.parseAlias(attr.restBatch || scope.$data.$uri);
            var uri  = $util.resolveUri(call.name, attr.uid ? attr.uid : null);
            var name = call.alias ? call.alias : "$batch";

            scope.$inline = attr.restInline || null;

            batch(uri, function(data){
                scope[name] = scope.$inline ? $util.group(data, scope.$inline) : data;
                scope.$uri = uri;
                scope.$name = name;
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Everything on `link` works perfectly, but the issue happens on `$search` inside the scope, the view is not updating, and even if i use `$apply()` it throws `$digest` error. Logging the scope inside the `$search` shows the new data, but yet the view is not updated

In case the view template is needed to see how it works, here it is:

```
<div layout="column" layout-fill rest-batch rest-inline="3">
    <div layout="row">
        <div flex="5"></div>
        <div flex="10" layout layout-align="center center">
            <md-button class="md-warn md-raised" ui-sref="plans.create">Create</md-button>
        </div> 
        <div flex="70" layout layout-align="center center">
            <md-button ui-sref="plans">Plans</md-button>
            <md-button ui-sref="plans.workouts">Workouts</md-button>
            <md-button ui-sref="plans.meals">Meals</md-button>
        </div>
        <md-input-container flex class="search">
            <label>Search Plans</label>
            <input ng-model="searchText" ng-keyup="$search(searchText)">
        </md-input-container>
    </div>
    <md-content flex ui-view="plans"></md-content>
</div>
```

***UPDATE*** i will add other factories and services to clear all questions about why they are used in the directive

restFactory:

```
app.factory("restFactory", ["Restangular", "userService", "$q", "utilityFactory", function($rest, $user, $q, $util){
    return {
        batch: function(uri, params){
            return $rest.all(params ? $util.parseParams(uri, params) : uri).getList({access_token: $user.getToken()});
        },
        detail: function(uri, id){
            return $rest.one(uri, id).get({access_token: $user.getToken()});
        },
        severalDetail: function(uri){
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var self = this;

            var collection = [];

            self.batch(uri).then(function(batch){
                for (var i = 0; i < batch.length; i++) {
                    self.detail(uri, batch[i].id).then(function(data){
                        collection.push(data);

                        if(batch.length == collection.length){
                            deferred.resolve(collection);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };

    function parseUri(uri){
        var regex = /\w+\/+\:+\w{2,}/g;

        var matches = uri.match(regex);

        matches.forEach(function(element, index){
            var res = resolveResource(element);

            if(res.resource == 'accounts'){
                res.value = $user.getId();
            }
        });
    }

    function resolveResource(uri){
        var arr = uri.split('/');

        return {
            resource: arr[0],
            parameter: arr[1] || null
        };
    }
}]);
```

utilityFactory:

```
app.factory("utilityFactory", ["userService","$httpParamSerializerJQLike", function($user, $serial){
    return {
        group: function(content, inline){
            var arrExt = [], index = 0;

            if(content.length <= inline){
                arrExt.push(content);
            }

            else{
                for(i = 0; i <= content.length / inline; i++){
                    var arrTemp = [];

                    for(e = 1; e <= inline; e++){
                        if(content[index])
                            arrTemp.push(content[index]);

                        index++;
                    }

                    arrExt.push(arrTemp);
                }
            }


            return arrExt;
        },
        parseAlias: function(exp){
            var regex = /\s+as\s+/;

            var obj = {
                name: null,
                alias: null
            };

            if(exp.match(regex)){
                var data = exp.split(regex);
                obj.alias = data[1];
                obj.name = data[0];
            }

            else{
                obj.name = exp;
            }

            return obj;
        },
        resolveUri: function(uri, id){
            return uri.replace("@id", id || $user.getId());
        },
        parseParams: function(uri, params){
            if(Object.prototype.toString.call(params) == "[object Object]"){
                for(p in params){
                    var param = ":" + p;

                    uri.replace(param, params[p]);
                }
            }

            return this.resolveUri(uri, params["@id"] || null);
        },
        querySearch: function(query){
            return $serial(query);
        }
    }
}])
```

userService

```
app.service('userService', ['$rootScope', '$resource', '$window', '$cookies', 'Restangular', function($rootScope, $resource, $window, $cookies, $rest){
    var self = this;
    var apiHost = 'http://' + $window.location.hostname + ':3000';

    /**
     * User cache data to access globally
     */
    self._data = {
        id: null,
        username: null,
        email: null,
        accessToken: null
    };

    /**
     * All messages for user
     */
    self._messages = {
        login: {
            error: {
                credentials: 'name/email or password is invalid.',
                accessToken: 'Provided token is invalid'
            }
        },
        register: {
            error: {
                credentials: 'Username is already taken.'
            },
            success: {
                credentials: 'User successfully created.'
            }
        },
        main: {
            error: {
                connection: 'Service error, please try again later.',
            }
        }
    };

    self.isGuest = true;

    /**
     * Populate all necesary data user cache
     * @param  {Object} data The data to populate
     */
    self._populate = function(data){
        self._data.id = data.id;
        self._data.username = data.username;
        self._data.email = data.user_email;
        self._accessToken = data.access_token;
    };

    /**
     * Get the name of the user from user cache
     * @return {String} The name of the user
     */
    self.getName = function(){
        return self._data.username;
    };

    /**
     * Get the id of the user from user cache
     * @return {Integer} The id of the user
     */
    self.getId = function(){
        return self._data.id;
    };

    /**
     * Get the access token of the current logged user
     * @return {String} Access token data
     */
    self.getToken = function(){
        return self._accessToken;
    };

    /**
     * Register a user with the given credentials and returns the result
     * @param  {Object}   credentials The credentials of the user
     * @param  {Function} callback    The callback to run when tries to register
     */
    self.register = function(credentials, callback){
        $rest.all('accounts').post(credentials).then(function(data){
            if(!data.passed){
                callback({
                    passed: false,
                    message: self._messages.register.error.credentials
                });
            }

            else{
                self.login(credentials, function(){});

                callback({
                    passed: true,
                    message: self._messages.register.success.credentials
                });
            }
        });
    };

    /**
     * Login the user with the given credentials and returns the result
     * @param  {Object}   credentials The credentials to send to server and login
     * @param  {Function} callback    The result of the server response
     */
    self.login = function(credentials, callback){
        $rest.all('accounts/login').post(credentials).then(function(data){
            var result = {
                success: false,
                error: null
            };

            if(typeof data.id !== "undefined"){
                self._populate(data);

                if(credentials.remember){
                    self.storeAccessToken(data.access_token);
                }

                self.isGuest = false;
                result.success = true;

                $rootScope.$broadcast('userLogged', (typeof credentials.token !== 'undefined'));
            }

            else{

                // Find if token was provided
                for(k in credentials){
                    // Return error message for token provided
                    if(k == 'token'){
                        result.error = self._messages.login.error.accessToken;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                // Return error message for invalid credentials
                if(!result.error)
                    result.error = self._messages.login.error.credentials;
            }

            callback(result.success, result.error);
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            callback(false, self._messages.main.error.connection);
        });
    };

    /**
     * Logs out the user by removing cache data and cookie data
     * @return {boolean} Either if operation was successfull or not
     */
    self.logout = function(){
        if(!self.isGuest){
            self.removeToken();

            for(prop in self._data)
                self._data[prop] = null;

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Store the access token of the user for auto re-login
     * @param {String} token The hash of the token to store in cookie
     * @return {void}
     */
    self.storeAccessToken = function(token){
        var time = new Date();

        $cookies.put('accessToken', token, {
            expires: new Date(time.getFullYear(), time.getMonth() + 1, time.getDate())
        });
    };

    /**
     * Remove the token stored in cookies if exists
     * @return {void}
     */
    self.removeToken = function(){
        if(self.hasToken)
            $cookies.remove('accessToken');
    };

    /**
     * Logs the user with a token stored in cookies
     * @param {function} 
     * @return {void}
     */
    self.logByToken = function(callback){
        if(self.hasToken()){
            self.login({token: $cookies.get('accessToken')}, function(success, error){
                callback(success, error);
            });
        }

        else
            callback(false, self._messages.login.error.accessToken);
    }

    /**
     * Check if client has token to access
     * @return {void}
     */
    self.hasToken = function(){
        if($cookies.get('accessToken'))
            return true;

        return false;
    }
}]);
```

Comment: can you share the code on plunker.

Comment: @RishiTiwari there are multiple files this directive depends on, it will take me time

Comment: @RishiTiwari i have tried to create the plunker, but it gives error that angular is not defined, i don't know why, here is the plunkr though https://plnkr.co/edit/NlWwdIXmg6U6O3qIjz4F?p=info

Comment: what is this "utilityFactory"..where you have implemented it

Comment: @RishiTiwari "utilityFactory" takes care about functions that most of the app use, like replacing, handling objects.. i have created a new plunker with utilityFactory https://plnkr.co/edit/GzzaXkq4UQPJPDivpxX6?p=info

Comment: Can't help you as your plunker does not contains all the required dependency...in your utilFactory you have a dependency called "UserService" where is that implemented...then in your HTML you have a different HTML than what you have posted...Create a plunker with all the dependencies and with exact codes..then only anyone can help you

Comment: @RishiTiwari i just need to know why the directive doesn't update the view, the directive handles the controller scope but when updated, the view doesn't change

Comment: Try updating an object....it happens sometime if you try updating a simple primitive type

Comment: @RishiTiwari the object updates, the directive receives the data from rest, everything works but the view changing

Comment: @RishiTiwari sorry for taking long to answer, i have added all other factories and services so you can see why they are used on the directive